# Kotlin: Type of 'exoPlayer' doesn't match the type of the overridden var-property 'public abstract var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? defined in

Tags: kotlin

I am not sure I understand what is going on here.
Please could someone explain?

---

I get the following error:
 `Type of 'exoPlayer' doesn't match the type of the overridden var-property 'public abstract var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? defined in...`

when I compile:

```
class LocalPlayback(context: Context, override var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer?) : Playback {
    private val context: Context
    //... other stuff...
    }
```

where LocalPlayback extends Playback:

```
interface Playback {
    var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer?
    //... other stuff...
    }
```

---

`SimpleExoPlayer` implements the `ExoPlayer` interface.

Answer (score 3):

A var allows both getting and setting of a value.  Overriding a var with a var of a more specific type is not possible in a type-safe way because using the super-type, they could set the value to a more general type, and then when someone uses the overridden var, it would be of the wrong type.  By changing the super-type to have a val, it prevents being able to set it to a general type, which eliminates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your exoPlayer variable as val in interface and everything would be ok.

```
interface Playback {
    val exoPlayer: ExoPlayer?
    //... other stuff...
    }
```

I made an example to test:

```
    interface Playback {
        val exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
    }

    class LocalPlayback(override var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer) : Playback 

    open class ExoPlayer
    class SimpleExoPlayer : ExoPlayer()
```

It compiles well. Maybe someone else could help us with explanation.